# What is the integration service name for CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

> I am trying to create AWS API gateway with AWS service integration with cloudwatch using AWS cdk/ cloudformation. But I am getting errors like "AWS service of type cloudwatch not supported". When I try to use Cloud watch log then it works but not for only cloudwatch.

```
Code
new AwsIntegrationProps
{
Region = copilotFoundationalInfrastructure.Region,
Options = new IntegrationOptions {
PassthroughBehavior = PassthroughBehavior.WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES,
CredentialsRole = Role.FromRoleArn(this,"CloudWatchAccessRole", "arn:aws:iam::800524210815:role/APIGatewayCloudWatchRole"),
RequestParameters = new Dictionary\<string, string\>()
{
{ "integration.request.header.Content-Encoding", "'amz-1.0'" },
{ "integration.request.header.Content-Type", "'application/json'" },
{ "integration.request.header.X-Amz-Target", "'GraniteServiceVersion20100801.PutMetricData'" },  
},
},
IntegrationHttpMethod = "POST",
Service = "cloudwatch", // this is working with s3 and logs
Action = "PutMetricData"
}
```

What is the correct service name for cloudwatch to putmetricsdata?

```
new AwsIntegrationProps
                {
                    Region = copilotFoundationalInfrastructure.Region,
                    Options = new IntegrationOptions {
                        PassthroughBehavior = PassthroughBehavior.WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES,
                        CredentialsRole = Role.FromRoleArn(this,"CloudWatchAccessRole", "arn:aws:iam::800524210815:role/APIGatewayCloudWatchRole"),
                        RequestParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
                        { 
                            { "integration.request.header.Content-Encoding", "'amz-1.0'" },
                            { "integration.request.header.Content-Type", "'application/json'" },
                            { "integration.request.header.X-Amz-Target", "'GraniteServiceVersion20100801.PutMetricData'" },    
                        },
                    },
                    IntegrationHttpMethod = "POST",
                    Service = "", // What will be the correct value for cloudwatch
                    Action = "PutMetricData"
                }
```

What will be the correct value for cloudwatch

Comment: We are able to create same api gateway endpoint using amazon console(UI), but we have to create this using cloud formation or cdk. 

We only need the correct service name for cloud watch.
S3-> s3
CloudWatchLogs ->logs
CloudWatch ->????

Answer (score 0):

For CloudWatch logs you put logs right?
So for CloudWatch, it is monitoring... I got it from a github code but cannot find it anymore.

Comment: We have to write custom metrics using api gateway endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to configure CloudWatch to monitor your API Gateway. First, you can create an AWS CloudWatch metric to monitor specific outputs produced by your API Gateway - see an example [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-apigateway-cloudwatch-dashboard/blob/main/lib/api-dashboard-stack.ts). The second way is to use the default configuration - see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-apigateway-readme.html#integration-targets:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20an%20IAM%20role%20will%20be%20created%20and%20associated%20with%20API%20Gateway%20to%20allow%20it%20to%20write%20logs%20and%20metrics%20to%20AWS%20CloudWatch%20unless%20cloudWatchRole%20is%20set%20to%20false.).

Comment: We have to write custom metrics using api gateway endpoint.